# Hibernate find object from database by few params

Tags: spring, hibernate

Can't find right query with few params.
Here is my query from DAO class:

```
public Notebook findByName(String name, Integer UserId) {
        return (Notebook) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Notebook where ....");
    }
```

I would like to get by this query object of Notebook by few params: **name** and **user id**(foreign key).

And i would like to get only one object, not list of objects even he has only 1 element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `createQuery(queryString)` returns a `Query` on which you can set the parameters e.g.

```
Query query = createQuery("from Notebook where id=:id and title=:title");
query.setParameter("id", id);
query.setParameter("title", title);
query.setMaxResults(1);
query.uniqueResult(); // fetch the object.
```

If the query returns more then one results be sure to set `setMaxResults()` or an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

First

Edit to

```
public Notebook findByName(String name, Integer UserId) {
        return (Notebook) ....createQuery("from Notebook where ....")...uniqueResult;
    }
```

BTW: I am not including the part where you are setting the parameters for your query

If there is no a unique result, [uniqueResult](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult%28%29) throws an exception.

Be sure your *query* statement is very specific and you are including something like **master.pk=child.fk** (where pk should fk)

could you update and include the complete query statement?

Comment: thanks for the uniqueResult.. but there was the question how to correct create query to get the object by two params (name and uerid)

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked for share your current query statement.

Comment: didn't quite understand what you mean by "query statement"

Comment: Sorry, bad english, the complete content within your *createQuery* method. The String...